# What is wrong with my function

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Hi there guys please don't be so harsh I'm new to coding and just need a little bit of help if that's ok, I'm trying to create a pHp registration form but I get this 1 error which is..

```
Notice: Undefined variable: register in D:\xampp\htdocs\loginscript\register.php on line 14
```

I have in my code:

```
if($register == 1 && !empty($_POST)) // Checks if the form is submitted or not
```

Please any help would be appreciated, thanks!

A user has requested to see my code.

```
<?php session_start();


 include ('header.php');

 ?> 


<?php
//Gets the form submitted data

if ( isset($_POST['register']) ) {}

if($register == 1 && !empty($_POST)) // Checks if the form is submitted or not

{

//retrieve all submitted data from the form

$username = $_POST['username'];
$username = strip_tags($username); //strip tags are used to take plain text only, in case the register-er inserts dangours scripts.
$username = str_replace(' ', '', $username); // to remove blank spaces

$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = strip_tags($password); 
$password = md5($password); // md5 is used to encrypt your password to make it more secure.

$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$full_name = strip_tags($full_name);

$location = $_POST['location'];
$location = strip_tags($location);

$gender = $_POST['gender'];


$sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; // checking username already exists
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 


//alert if it already exists
if($num_rows > 0) 
{
echo '
<div class="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>username already exists!</strong> please choose another username
</div>
';
}

else 
{
// if username doesn't exist insert new records to database
 $success = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username, password, fullname, location, gender) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$full_name','$location','$gender')");


 //messages if the new record is inserted or not
if($success) { 
echo '
<div class="alert alert-success">
Registration Successful ! please login to your account
</div>
';
} 

else {
echo '
<div class="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>Registration Unsuccessful! </strong> please try again
</div>
';


}

}

}
?>

<br/>
   <div style="float:right; "> <a class="btn" href="index.php" > <i class="icon-home icon-black"></i> Home </a>  </div>
   <br/>
<?php
//hiding form once the registration is successful
if( isset( $_REQUEST['success'] ) ) {
  $user = $_REQUEST['success'];
}
 ?>
<form action="register.php?register=1" method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
  <fieldset>

    <legend>Sign Up Form</legend>
    <label>Username *</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Type something…">
    <br/>
    <label>Password * <font color="red"> Minnimum length 8 </font> </label>
    <input name="password" type="password" required="required" <input pattern=".{8,100}" placeholder="Type something…">
    <br/>
    <label>Full Name *</label>
    <input name="full_name" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Type something…">
    <br/>
    <label>Email * </label>
    <input name="location" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Type something…">
    <br/>
    <label>Gender </label>
    <select name="gender">
  <option>Male</option>
  <option>Female</option>
</select>







  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validate()
{
   if( document.myForm.username.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your username!" );
     document.myForm.username.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.myForm.password.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your password!" );
     document.myForm.password.focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   if( document.myForm.full_name.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your full name!" );
     document.myForm.full_name.focus() ;
     return false;
   }

   return( true );
}
//-->
</script> 

    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Signup</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<?php  ?>















<?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the form code and the PHP code where you sent your form at?

Comment: And how are you defining this `$register` variable in your code?

Comment: @John Conde I know but I don't understand it. That's why I am asking for help.

Comment: @GaijinJim I've added my code